# Implicit use of destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class with a deleted destructor (in practice, it needs outside help to be destroyed):

```
struct indestructible {
    indestructible(indestructible&&);
    ~indestructible() = delete;
};
```

When I try to use its move constructor, the compiler complains:

```
struct user {
   indestructible ind;
   user(indestructible&& ind) : ind(std::move(ind)) {}
};

indestructible.cc:11:3: error: attempt to use a deleted function
user(indestructible&& ind) : ind(std::move(ind)) {}
^
indestructible.cc:6:3: note: '~indestructible' has been explicitly marked  deleted here
    ~indestructible() = delete;
```

What's going on? there are no other members that could throw, and neither does the constructor body, so why is there any cause for the move constructor to invoke the destructor?

Comment: If `indestructible` can't be destructed, how could any object containing it be destructed?

Comment: Note that `user`'s destructor will still attempt to destruct `ind`

Comment: A (slightly) better solution than a deleted destructor might be a protected or private destructor, and the user must derive or be friended.  Alternatively you could design the object so that it can actually have a normal destructor, and special work be done in the constructor instead

Comment: user would be destroyed via something similar to std::unique_ptr<user, user_destroyer>; user_destroyer::operator() would perform the operations needed to clean up user and indestructible.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a private destructor, because I don't want it called under any circumstances -- there really is no way to destroy indestructible without outside information.

Comment: btw, my workaround is to place ind in a union with its own do-nothing constructor/destructor and manage it manually; but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[class.base.init]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#12):

> In a non-delegating constructor, the destructor for each direct or
>   virtual base class and for each non-static data member of class type
>   is potentially invoked (12.4). [ *Note*: This provision ensures that
>   destructors can be called for fully-constructed sub-objects in case an
>   exception is thrown (15.2). —*end note* ]

[[class.dtor]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#11v):

> A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is
>   deleted or not accessible from the context of the invocation.

No exception is made for a constructor that doesn't throw. See also [CWG 1915](http://wg21.link/cwg1915).

Answer (score 7):

When your `user` object gets out of scope, it is destructed. Its members are destructed, including the `indestructible` member, and that's impossible since its destructor is deleted.

Comment: In my example, the user object never gets out of any scope.

Consider:

    `auto user = new user(std::move(*new indestructible));`

so `user`'s destructor is never called.

Consider also the compiler error message's context -- it's `user`'s move constructor. Why does it have to instantiate the destructor there?

Comment: Since the "moving" an object does not mean that the object moved from ceases to exist. `auto a = std::move (b);` does not destroy `b`. It's up to the programmer implementing the move constructor which state it is in. For the compiler, the lifetime of `b` ends when `b` gets out of scope.

Comment: In addition, `: ind(std::move(ind))` works on the parameter `ind`, which is a variable and thus goes out of scope at the end of your move constructor. Hence you need not even destroy a `user` to run into problems.

Comment: Except that `ind` the parameter is a reference and destroying it is a no-op.